# How to redraw flot chart in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, flot

I am using [flot chart Angularjs directive](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular-flot) to draw a stacked bar chart. When I make a async call to an end point to fetch data for chart, it is unable show up. I suspect it needs to redraw. There is a [draw()](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-options) function which looks like re draws flot chart. Please help me re-draw my flot chart in Angularjs.

```
<flot dataset="tasksRunData" options="tasksRunChartOptions" class="center-block" width="100%" height="400px" id="reportTasksRunRange.id"></flot>

angular.module('myApp').controller('Step2Controller', function($scope, $location, $interval, dialogs, $modal, $transition, ReportingService) {

    ...

    $scope.tasksRunData = mainArray;
    $scope.tasksRunChartOptions = {
        legend: {
            show: true,
            margin: 2
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: yaxisArray,
            alignTicksWithAxis: "right"
        },
        grid: {
            labelMargin: 10,
            hoverable: true,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: {
            stack: true
        },
        colors: colorCodesArray,
        tooltip: true
    };

    ...
    $scope.redrawTasksRunDataHistoByChart();
    ...

    $scope.redrawTasksRunDataHistoByChart = function() {
        $scope.tasksRunData.draw(); //TypeError: undefined is not a function
        alert("AAAA");
    }
});
```

**Update**

```
ReportService.getTasksRunDateHistoByType().then(function(result) {
    $scope.renderTasksRunDateHistoByType(result);
});

$scope.renderTasksRunDateHistoByType = function(jsonInput) {
            console.log(json[RUN_AGG_BY_DATE_HISTO].aggregations[TASK_TYPE_AGG].buckets);
    var yaxis = [];
    var buckets = json[RUN_AGG_BY_DATE_HISTO].aggregations[TASK_TYPE_AGG].buckets;
    var log = [];
    var mainArray = [];
    var colorCodes = ["#5C832F","#7B52AB","#263248","#AB1A25","#FF8598","#AB1A25","#FEB41C","#193441","#193441","#BEEB9F","#E3DB9A","#917A56"],
        idx = 0;
    angular.forEach(buckets, function(value, key) {        
        this.push(key + ': ' + value +", "+value["key"]);
        var dataArray = [], index = 0;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value[RUN_OVER_TIME_KEY]["buckets"]));
        angular.forEach(value[RUN_OVER_TIME_KEY]["buckets"], function(value, key) {
            var dataArr = [];
            dataArr.push('['+index+', '+value["doc_count"]+']');
            dataArray.push(dataArr);

            yaxis.push(JSON.parse('['+index+', "'+$scope.translate(value["key"])+'", "'+value["key"]+'"]'));

            index++;
        }, log);
        var barObject = '"bars": {"show": "true", "barWidth":0.8, "fillColor": "'+colorCodes[idx]+'", "order": 1, "align": "center"}';
        var object = '{ "data": ['+dataArray+'], "label": "'+value["key"]+'", '+barObject+'}';
        mainArray.push(JSON.parse(object));
        idx++;
    }, log);

    console.log(yaxis);
    $scope.tasksRunData = mainArray;
    $scope.tasksRunChartOptions = {
        legend: {
            show: true,
            margin: 2
        },
        xaxis: {
            //ticks:[[0,'Oct 4'],[1,'Oct 5'],[2,'Oct 6'],[3,'Oct 7'],[4,'Oct 8'],[5,'Oct 9']],
            ticks: yaxis,
            alignTicksWithAxis: "right"
        },
        grid: {
            labelMargin: 10,
            hoverable: true,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: {
            stack: true
        },
        colors: colorCodes,
        tooltip: true
    };
};
```

angularjs service

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('ReportService', function ReportService($http, $q) {

        var getTasksRunDateHistoByType = function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:4040/reports/taskRun",
                data: '{ "client_user_info": { "client_id": "MU03"}}'
            }).
            success(function(result, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }).
            error(function(result, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Error");
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        return {
            getTasksRunDateHistoByType: getTasksRunDateHistoByType
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code to the directive, it'll redraw automatically when `$scope.dataset` changes.

```
  $scope.redrawChart = function() {
    var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      tmp.push([i,Math.random() * 10]);
    }
    $scope.dataset = [{ data: tmp }];
  };
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tfYmpNEtPMayknHGfTds?p=preview).

**EDITS FOR UPDATES**

I'm having a hard time following your code, but in the end, you'll end up in the `$scope.renderTasksRunDateHistoByType` with data in the variable `jsonInput`.  You then store some variable `mainArray` (which doesn't exist as far as I can tell) into other `$scope` level variables.  I never see you assign data back to `$scope.dataset`.  This is what the flot directive is watching to trigger a redraw.  It's just that simple.

```
   $scope.renderTasksRunDateHistoByType = function(jsonInput) {
      $scope.dataset = [{
        data: jsonInput
      }];

      //console.log(jsonInput);
      //$scope.tasksRunData = mainArray;
      //$scope.tasksRunChartOptions
      //getting data here once response is received from server
    };
```

See updates [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QO3Iiz10DlFpndBPwAH8?p=preview).

Comment: hmm.. Not sure why my flot is not getting rendered when data is received via a rest end point. Flot chart displays correctly when applied hardcoded same data. I verified data in chrome debugger. Is there a way I can manually trigger re-draw in angularjs?

Comment: @abi1964, Instead of trying to work around your problem, update your question with the specifics of it (the async call).  Show the code where you re-assign `$scope.dataset` with your new data.

Comment: Thanks. Please can you take a look at an extended [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034462/what-would-be-optimal-way-to-change-flot-chart-data-array-depending-on-range-sel)?