# How to get smooth range stepping using rzajac slider in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, slider, flot

This question is in continuation to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034462/what-would-be-optimal-way-to-change-flot-chart-data-array-depending-on-range-sel) which was answered by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16363/mark)

I am using [rzajac slider](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider) to control my chart. The slider values are date, given in milliseconds, but when I move forward the slider steps twice and for step value of a day `86400000` (got step value by subtracting 2 date millisecond values `(1412467200000-1412380800000)`). Also the chart crops the bar on it's edges when the chart value changes.

Can anyone help me with the following questions?

```
1. Is it correct way to step a day? how can I provision it for hours?
2. How to show whole bar, without cropping when applying a filter on button click or slider change?
3. Need help with smooth transition for changing date range with rzajac slider plugin
```

Here is [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KXrcxI5hfmC8PE6IPmyR?p=preview)

Below is my code

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <rzslider rz-slider-floor="reportTasksRunRange.floor" rz-slider-ceil="reportTasksRunRange.ceil" rz-slider-model="reportTasksRunRange.min" rz-slider-high="reportTasksRunRange.max" rz-slider-translate="translate" rz-slider-step="{{reportTasksRunRange.step}}">
    </rzslider>
    <flot dataset="tasksRunData" options="tasksRunChartOptions" class="center-block" width="100%" height="400px" min="reportTasksRunRange.min" max="reportTasksRunRange.max"></flot>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div>{{reportTasksRunRange.min}} is "{{translate(reportTasksRunRange.min)}}"</div>
    <div>Stepping {{reportTasksRunRange.step}}</div>
    <h2>Filter date range</h2>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="applyFilterClick($event)">Apply Filter</button>

  </div>

var colorCodes = ["#8CC051", "#967BDC", "#5D9CEC", "#FB6E52", "#EC87BF", "#46CEAD", "#FFCE55", "#193441", "#193441", "#BEEB9F", "#E3DB9A", "#917A56"];
$scope.tasksRunChartOptions = {
  legend: {
    show: true,
    margin: 2
  },
  xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
    minTickSize: [1, "day"]
  },
  grid: {
    labelMargin: 10,
    hoverable: true,
    borderWidth: 0
  },
  series: {
    stack: true
  },
  colors: colorCodes,
  tooltip: true
};

$scope.translate = function(value) {
  var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  var myDate = new Date(value);
  //return myDate.toLocaleString();
  return myDate.getDate() + " " + monthNames[myDate.getMonth()] + " " + myDate.getFullYear();
}

$scope.reportTasksRunRange = {
  min: 1412380800000,
  max: 1412812800000, 
  floor: 1412380800000,
  ceil: 1412812800000,
  step: (1412467200000 - 1412380800000)
};

$scope.tasksRunData = [{"data":[[1412380800000,477],[1412467200000,3015],[1412553600000,2988],[1412640000000,3123],[1412726400000,2970],[1412812800000,2295]],"label":"DSS","bars":{"show":"true","barWidth":54000000,"fillColor":"#8CC051","order":1,"align":"center"}}];

$scope.applyFilterClick = function($event) {
  $scope.reportTasksRunRange.min = 1412380800000;
  $scope.reportTasksRunRange.max = 1412640000000;
    //$scope.reportTasksRunRange.max = $scope.reportTasksRunRange - (1412467200000 - 1412380800000);
}
```

**Update**

[Updated plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAk9Hf76gn4oNcZTWBtl?p=preview) also providing data with hourly changes to filter based on hours for a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple problems here:

1.) `flot` is plotting in UTC, your slider is in local time.  I'm UTC -5 and this produces a disconnect between the dates.

2.) The double jump of the slider for each date is talked about [here](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/issues/16).  Unfortunately, it's a "feature" of the slider and fixing it requires modifying the source.

3.) Your "half" bar is not surprising, since it sets the min/max to the start of the day and the bar spans across the day.  To fix that, I'd introduce a bar min/max padding value in the directive:

```
 // I created and set options.xaxis.minMaxPad to 12 hours (43200000) in the flot config object
 scope.$watch('dataset', onDatasetChanged, true);
  onMinChanged = function(min, _, scope) {
    if (plot) {
      plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].min = min - scope.options.xaxis.minMaxPad;
      plot.setupGrid();
      return plot.draw();
    }
 };
```

Here's an [updated example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhSFgSsX0tXsHnAoSNPT?p=preview) putting this all together.

Comment: Thank you Mark, you have answered all of my questions except is it correct way to step a day `(1412467200000-1412380800000)`, how can I provision stepping on per hour basis? I have updated my question with a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAk9Hf76gn4oNcZTWBtl?p=preview) which includes hourly data.

Comment: @abi1964, the step becomes the number of milliseconds in time frame.  So 1 hour is 3600000 milliseconds.  Your other problem is that you are explicitly setting the `barWidth` to 15 hours, so decrease that to under an hour or remove it altogether and let flot pick the appropriate `barWidth`.  Updates [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Csufz6ZU3yE0ELtlFEA?p=preview)

Comment: @abi1964, you are welcome, your questions are interesting, sounds like you are working on a fun project.